# how to "Dynamically move the text area to top of the page by clicking submit button" in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to perform by clicking submit button the text area should move to the top of page with delete button right side.Whenever I click submit button the textarea  should go to the top of the page and append the previous textarea with delete button right side.I have attached my code and codesandox link . Kindly help me to solve this functionality.[Codesandboxdemo](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-platform-m508q).

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: [],
     
    };
}
handleSubmit(index)
  {
   
  }
 add(e) {
    this.setState({ count: [...this.state.count, ""] });
  }
 handleChange(e, index) {
    const { count } = this.state;
    count[index] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ count });
  }
render() {
    const {  count } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <label>Enter the text</label>
        {count.map((counts, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <input
               
                onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, index)}
                value={counts}
              
              />
             
              <button onClick={() => this.handleSubmit(index)}>submit</button>
             
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <button  onClick={(e) => this.add(e)}> Add</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which you can do it one is the css way and another is the javascript way , you can take a new state boolean and change the state when the submit button is clicked and you can toggle with ternary operator , or else you can use a css class and change it when the submit button is clicked, If you need the code tell me , I will post it here

Comment: can you please post the code using the css way @Goutham JM

Comment: hii @Goutham JM can you kindly share the code to solve this issue